# Google maps Pincode latitude-longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

How do I get postal code value for a location if I have Latitude and Longitude values of that location

Comment: I have edited the answer take a look

Comment: Abhay the answer below is right or wrong i dont know. Remember getting address from lat/long is called geocoding and getting lat/long from address is called reverse geocoding . so do look of it while coding next time on google maps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use getPostalCode() for this.

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
            Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> add;
    try {

        add = geo.getFromLocation(taplat, taplon, 1);
        addstr = add.get(0).getPostalCode(); //u'll get postal code in addstr

    }
```