# Get Pincode alone for a latitude / longitude

Tags: google-maps

I want to get postal code (pincode of a location) using Google Maps with a given latitude / longitude.

I know the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965162/google-maps-pincode-latitude-longitude) but the problem is that, that requires Reverse GeoCoding.

Reverse geo coding is limited and I cannot afford to buy an enterprise license.

So is there a separate API call that can give just the postal code without having to take it from the "address" piece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need buy any enterprise license. You can get postal code by using Google map's API. You can get the postal code from the json data returned by the API. Provide the lat lng to LatLng constructor.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (results[0]) {
            var add = results[0].formatted_address ;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Is it not invoking a reverse gecoding API? If yes, calling this, if i exceed a quota, i may have to buy a  license at some point of time. So there is no way to get *just* the pincode ?

Comment: It is, but I have called this API almost 500 times or more I dont remember but I didnt get any such issue. BTW did you get what you need for the time being?

Comment: Yes, like i said, i had the answer already done elsewhere (i created a link for it). but my question was clearly to understand how to do without postal code. I would wait for some more time to check if i get some specific answers, else i will mark you up.

Comment: Hi, Have you get solution ? because I am also facing same issue.